# Program failed to complete: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (12884933924 > 1280)

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, anchor-lang

I'm getting an error while executing an initialise code in my smart contract. I'm using Anchor Framework for my code. Below is the struct and the account:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeAdminList<'info> {
    // Admin list PDA Account
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"adminlist".as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = 16 + AdminListAccount::MAX_SIZE
    )]
    pub admin_list_pda: Account<'info, AdminListAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct AdminListAccount {
    // Admin address List
    pub admin_list: Vec<Pubkey>,
}

impl AdminListAccount {
    pub const MAX_SIZE: usize = 4 + (10 * 32);
}
```

Below is the code in React app:

```
async function initializeAdminList() {
    const provider = await getProvider();
    /* create the program interface combining the idl, program ID, and provider */
    const program = new Program(idl, programID, provider);
    try {
      const [adminList, bumpAdmin] =
          await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [utf8.encode("adminlist")],
            program.programId
          );

      console.log("adminListPDA", adminList.toString(), "bump", bumpAdmin);

      const trans = await program.methods
        .initializeAdminList()
        .accounts({
          adminListPda: adminList,
          authority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
          systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        })
        .rpc();

      console.log("trans", trans);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Transaction error: ", err);
    }
  }
```

When I run this code, I get the below error:

"Program failed to complete: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (12884933924 > 1280)"

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you share more on the logs or link to the explorer with this tx

Comment: Logs:

0
: 
"Program 8weVzacVFidiqk1cJxezhLrqayHpFtKi7qyA76d7oLab invoke [1]"
1
: 
"Program log: Instruction: InitializeAdminList"
2
: 
"Program 8weVzacVFidiqk1cJxezhLrqayHpFtKi7qyA76d7oLab consumed 7816 of 200000 compute units"
3
: 
"Program failed to complete: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (12884933924 > 1280)"
4
: 
"Program 8weVzacVFidiqk1cJxezhLrqayHpFtKi7qyA76d7oLab failed: Program failed to complete"

Answer (score 3):

Found the resolution:

I was using Solana version 1.16.0 which was causing the issue. I downgraded to 1.14.18 and it solved the problem.

Comment: Found detailed discussion at github issues: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/31960
Kind of "It's a bigger risk for programs to behave unexpectedly or incorrectly, so even though it's painful in the short term, people must find a way to get their dependencies up to date to use the newer compiler." (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/31960#issuecomment-1674740803)

Answer (score 1):

"Program 8weVzacVFidiqk1cJxezhLrqayHpFtKi7qyA76d7oLab consumed 7816 of 200000 c.rpc(
Found the resolution:

I was using Solana version 1.16.0 which was causing the issue. I downgraded to 1.14.18 and it solved the problem.);

```
  console.log("trans", trans);Logs: 0 : "Program 8weVzacVFidiqk1cJxezhLrqayHpFtKi7qyA76d7oLab invoke [1]" 1 : "Program log: Instruction: InitializeAdminList"

} catch (err) {
   console.log("adminListPDA", adminList.toString(), "bump", bumpAdmin);

  const trans = await program units"
```

Comment: InitializeAdminList"

    } catch (err) {
       console.log("adminListPDA", adminList.toString(), "bump", bumpAdmin);"Program 8weVzacVFidiqk1cJxezhLrqayHpFtKi7qyA76d7oLab invoke [1]" 1 : "Program log: Instruction: InitializeAdminList"[Buffer.from("adminlist", "utf-8")],
            program.programId
          );

Answer (score 0):

You get this error sometimes when you accidentally pass a String or other object instead of a pubkey in your accounts args. The combined size of the bytes for accounts + args must be < 1280 in legacy txes.

Make sure SystemProgram is imported correctly and check the wallet is what you expect.

```
    try {
      const [adminList, bumpAdmin] =
          PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
            [Buffer.from("adminlist", "utf-8")],
            program.programId
          );

      console.log("adminListPDA", adminList.toString(), "bump", bumpAdmin);

      const trans = await program.methods
        .initializeAdminList()
        .accounts({
          adminListPda: adminList,
          authority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
          systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        })
        .rpc();

      console.log("trans", trans);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Transaction error: ", err);
    }
```

If that's not it, then Solana is having troubling serializing your struct as given. You didn't pass a Vec to the init ix, so it doesn't know what size to give the Vec. Try initializing the Vec with PubKey default placeholders instead of just specifying the size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me reply 1 by 1 on the questions asked:

1. I am passing only pubkeys in the account args.
2. There are no args to this method, and only 3 accounts, so the combined size must be less than 1280 characters.
3. SystemProgram and wallet are correct.
4. I removed the Vector in my struct to check if that's causing the issue. I now have a single pubkey field and even that is throwing same error.

I don't understand what's the issue. Any further help will be highly appreciated.