# failed to complete: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (12884932868 > 1280)

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, cargo

I am trying to optimize size of my code by moving logic to freeze and approve in a separate file. However when I deploy and try to call my contract, I am getting error:

```
'Program 8uupFNMrGzDnmXX1un2C5mYU3mXGHjRnzjYKzWig1RP consumed 11491 of 200000 compute units',
'Program failed to complete: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (12884932868 > 1280)',
```

main.rs:

```
use crate::utility::{self, freeze};
    ...
    ...
    pub fn handler(ctx: Context<Initialize>,..){
                freeze(&ctx.accounts.initializer.to_account_info(), &ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            asset_manager, ctx.accounts.initializer_deposit_token_account.clone(),
            &ctx.accounts.metadata_program.to_account_info(), &ctx.accounts.edition.to_account_info(),
            &ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),ctx.program_id, true)?;
    }
```

utility.rs:

```
pub fn freeze<'info>(initializer: &AccountInfo<'info>,mint: &AccountInfo<'info>, asset_manager: &mut Box<Account<'info, AssetManager>>,
initializer_deposit_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>, metadata_program: &AccountInfo<'info>, edition: &AccountInfo<'info>,
token_program: &AccountInfo<'info>, program_id: &Pubkey, approve: bool)-> Result<()>{
    // Approve NFT delegation
    let (_escrow_pda, escrow_bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[&mint.key().to_bytes()], program_id);
    let escrow_authority_seeds = &[asset_manager.mint.as_ref(), &[escrow_bump]];
    if approve{
        let _escrow_signer = &[&escrow_authority_seeds[..]];
        let cpi_accounts = Approve {
        to: initializer_deposit_token_account.to_account_info(),
        delegate: asset_manager.to_account_info(),
        authority: initializer.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_program = token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
        token::approve(cpi_context, 1)?;
    }
    // Freeze NFT account
    let edition_info = find_master_edition_account(&mint.key());
    invoke_signed(
        &freeze_delegated_account(
            metadata_program.key(),
            asset_manager.key(),
            initializer_deposit_token_account.key(),
            edition_info.0,
            mint.key(),
        ),
        &[
            asset_manager.to_account_info(),
            initializer_deposit_token_account.to_account_info(),
            edition.to_account_info(),
            mint.to_account_info(),
        ],
        &[escrow_authority_seeds],
    )?; 
    Ok(())
}
```

However, if I copy logic from utility to main, it works fine.

Comment: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/program-failed-to-complete-instruction-passed-to-inner-instruction-is-too-large

Comment: even with solana 14.18/19 I am getting this error

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue at compile time, check the following:

- Solana CLI v1.14.20
- Add `solana-program = "=1.14.20"` to Anchor.toml